# Indian Financial year in bootstrap date-picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Bootstrap DatePicker and I want to show the Indian financial year like `2019-20`, `2020-21` and so on.

```
jQuery('#year').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    orientation: "bottom",
    format: "yyyy",
    startDate: '-1Y',
    endDate: '+0Y',
    viewMode: "years", 
    minViewMode: "years"
});
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Does changing the date format works for you?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery('#year').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        orientation: "bottom",
        format: "yyyy",
        startDate: '-1Y',
        endDate: '+0Y',
        // viewMode: "years", 
        minViewMode: 2,
    }).on('hide',function(date){
  $("#year").val(date.target.value + "-" + (parseInt(date.target.value) + parseInt(1)));
});

Comment: i got solution 

Thank you all of you